# How to enable upload key option in teamcity

Tags: bitbucket, teamcity

How to enable upload key option in teamcity?
[image]
and also to use that from bitbucket

Answer (score 0):

If you go back to the Project page there is an SSH keys option.
You can then Upload an SSH key.

[image]